# Duplicated Makefile commands with differing variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile for tagging/pushing docker images that looks like this:

```
AWS_DEV_ACCT = 12345
AWS_PROD_ACCT = 67890
VERSION = 1.5

stage-dev:
    docker tag myapp:latest $(AWS_DEV_ACCT).dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:$(VERSION)
    docker push $(AWS_DEV_ACCT).dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:$(VERSION)

stage-prod:
    docker tag myapp:latest $(AWS_PROD_ACCT).dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:$(VERSION)
    docker push $(AWS_PROD_ACCT).dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:$(VERSION)
```

As you can see, the commands for `stage-dev` and `stage-prod` are identical, with the exception of the aws account number.

Is there a way to encapsulate this variable somehow, so I don't need to repeat the entire block of commands?  (The real makefile has quite a bit more duplication than this example.)

I'm using GNU Make 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a constructed variable name; like this:

```
dev_AWS_ACCT = 12345
prod_AWS_ACCT = 67890
VERSION = 1.5

stage-%:
        docker tag myapp:latest $($*_AWS_ACCT).dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:$(VERSION)
        docker push $($*_AWS_ACCT).dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:$(VERSION)
```

Here, the automatic variable `$*` expands to the stem of the target (the part that matches the `%`), and so you get `$(dev_AWS_ACCT)` which then expands to   `12345` or `$(prod_AWS_ACCT)` which expands to `67890`.

You might be interested in this post, and the associated ones: https://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/

Comment: A bit unrelated, but thought you may like to know https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1158#issuecomment-1552323325

Answer (score 1):

If the crucial variables are *not* so conveniently named, then the best approach might be to use [target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
stage-dev: ACCT:=$(AWS_DEV_ACCT)
stage-prod: ACCT:=$(AWS_PROD_ACCT)

stage-dev stage-prod:
    docker tag myapp:latest $(ACCT).dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:$(VERSION)
    docker push $(ACCT).dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:$(VERSION)
```